# How to use Selenium to check for memory leaks in javascript app?

Tags: javascript, selenium, memory-leaks, selenium-chromedriver

I am using java + selenium for automated testing of a javascript web-app. One question that has come up is memory leaks and how to test for them. Since I am already using selenium for testing the app, is there an easy way to get the memory usage and other profiling information for the web app? (leveraging selenium or/and other automated web-js testing tools)

Currently I'm using chromedriver but will be extending to use the firefox and ie drivers in the future.

Comment: were you able to find any such approach of capturing performance footprint of your website through selenium or any such other tool ? . Request you to share your finding , as it would be helpful for other people . Thanks in advance.

Comment: @sjethvani We did some javascript heap exports by injecting/executing js code via selenium but that didn't end up getting all the info we wanted. I don't work there anymore so I can't post the sample code of how we worked around this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, cant be done with selenium solely, take a look into tools like dynaTrace or httpWatch. Those can be integrated with webDriver.
Also, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18812326/alternatives-for-automated-web-application-front-end-performance-testing) thread here.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium does not monitor any resource usage, it is just a way to emulate user actions. You could use Windows `tasklist` command to get the memory usage of your browser. Modern browsers spawn many processes so remember to check all of those.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium itself doesn't help report on that.
The main way I could imagine it helping out would be to have a bunch of machines runnning cases with different inputs and expected outputs and make sure that each one gives the correct output when they're run at the same time.